# Output json response from url using libcurl in Native Tizen wearable

Tags: c, json, libcurl, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I'm currently new to Native Tizen Development and libcurl as well. So I have an API/URL that accepts post data and echo json array to be parsed using tizen watch gear s2. I was able to succeed in using curl_easy_perform, however I don't know how to check or retrieve the response from the URL. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking for how to receive the data in memory using the libcurl API? If so, the curl example [getinmemory.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) is showing exactly that!

Comment: yes, sorry I'm new to this and im not that good with c. I followed the tutorial however I can't understand how/where to print the data received .

Comment: ok so i figured out that there was a contents variable in: WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp).  Thank you.